# How can i get name of launched cmd?

Tags: linux, filenames

I am running .cmd files under linux, in order to run SAS programs, and I need to dynamically get the .cmd filename that it has been launched.

For example if the launched file is "generate_1234.cmd", i need to extract "generate_1234".

I have looked for a solution but I couldn't find the appropriate command to get the filename after launching the .cmd file.

Please note that my knowlege about LInux is close to 0.

10x

Comment: what is .cmd? in linux file extensions do not matter. what is this file, is it a shell script?

Comment: Can you pass command line arguments to your .cmd file (whatever that is...). By convention, the 0th argument is usually the name of the program. For example, in shell scripts, $0 is the script name, $1 is the first argument, $2 the second.

Comment: Are you sure you're not referring Linux the wrong way like it's the command-line? `.cmd` files run in windows command prompt i.e. cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a shell script you can extract the file name by using $0. $[number] are variables in bash that refer to the command line arguments, with $0 being the name of the actual file that is being executed. if all you need is the file name without the extension, you can use sed for that. for example

```
name=$(echo $0 | sed -e "s/\..\+//")
```

that would set name to "generate_1234".